# Async / await in Typescript and with cheerio

Tags: typescript, async-await, cheerio

I want to understand how **async / await** works with cheerio (in my example).

- As far as i can guess: I have to wait for the request to be done. So I should use `await Promise.all()` in front of the request?
- Do I have to wait for this function: `cheerio.load(html);`?
- What about `$('article').each`?
- How then does everything come together in the main class so that after all urls have been processed, the `processMailer` method is called?

It would be super nice if you can explain the why a little bit! :)

## In my Project

### The goal:

I want to scrape deals from different urls. In the end everything should be wrapped up and send via mail.

### The problem:

The mail is sent before the scraper scraped all urls.

### The Code:

```js
class Main {
    const startScraper = (user: User) => {
        user.dealGroups.forEach((dealGroup, index) => {
            const url = baseUrl + dealGroup;
        
            // Get deals from url
            scrapeDealsFromUrl(url, (scrapedDeals) => {
      
                if (scrapedDeals.length == 0) {
                console.log(`No deals scraped - ${url}`);
                return;
                }
        
        
                await deleteFilesOnWeekday(); // Reset files on sunday
        
                const oldDeals = readFromFile(dealGroup);
                const newDeals = checkForDuplicates(scrapedDeals, oldDeals);
                saveToFile([...newDeals, ...oldDeals], dealGroup);
      
          });
        });
    }
        
    processMailer(newDeals, dealGroup);
}
```

```js
class Scraper {
    type DealCallback = (err: Deal[], deals?: Deal[]) => void;

    export function scrapeDealsFromUrl(url: string, callback: DealCallback) {
        // get data from mydealz and get the articles
        request(url, (error, response, html) => {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);
                const deals: Deal[] = [];

                $('article').each(function (i, element) {

                    deals[i] = new DealBuilder()
                        .withTitle($(this).find('.thread-link').text())
                        .withPrice(extractNumberFromString($(this).find('.thread-price').text()))
                        .withPriceWas(extractNumberFromString($(this).find('span').find('.mute--text, .text--lineThrough').text()))
                        .withImageUrl($(this).find('img').attr('src'))
                        .withLink($(this).find('.boxAlign-jc--all-c, .btn--mode-primary').attr('href'))
                        .withScrapedDate(new Date())
                        .build();
                });
                return callback(deals)
            }
            return callback([]);
        });
    }
}
```

I already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55821324/how-to-get-the-function-returns-with-async-await-methods), but I do not understand the answer.

Thanks for any hints or help!

Comment: You're using the [outdated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) callback-based `request` library. Instead, use a modern promise-based library like axios or `fetch`. Once you do, there are hundreds of examples of how to use these alongside Cheerio, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75400938/6243352). Cheerio is fully synchronous--it's just the request that's async.

Comment: Thangs for the advice. Now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of promise to get the request data, parse it, and send to the callback. It might look like this:

```
export function scrapeDealsFromUrl(url: string, callback: DealCallback) {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    request(url, (error, response, html) => {
      // deals code here
      let deals = []
      resolve(deals)
    })
  }).then(callback)
}
```